# How to reset default Minecraft skin to Steve?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I liked the Steve skin, but then the default skin was set to Alex. I don't mind Alex, but I want my default set back to Steve. When opening the MC launcher, I changed the skin to the Steve skin file that is in the MC assets folder. This gave me the Steve skin, but it treated the Steve skin like a *downloaded* skin, not a *default*. The problem with this? It didn't work with texture/resource packs. For example, I have a Gravity Falls pack that changes Steve to Dipper Pines. But when I have the Steve on, it won't change to Dipper!! Any advice?

Comment: This is a little bit confusing. Can you clarify what end results you want?

Comment: I want this: When I set my skin to default, I want it as Steve, and I want it changeable with resource packs. Is that any clear-er? :D

Comment: Oh yeah... that's a LOT shorter and understandable than what you just wrote. xD

Comment: Sorry. Btw, just found out that I can't change it. I get that default randomly based of my Account ID, and there's no way to change it...

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: I searched it on www.mojang.net. They said so.. >:'(

Comment: wat spam support tickets maybe xD

Comment: I was going to answer with you can't because of the random assigning based on ID but you found it out yourself.  You should answer your own question as you did the research and figured out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops... Just found it out myself...
Apparently you can't change your default, because it's randomly decided based
on your account ID...

Answer (score 0):

This will change the skin for your Minecraft account. You can change your player model between *Steve* and *Alex* in two ways:

- Minecraft Launcher (**NEW LAUNCHER ONLY**)

  Go to the "Skins" tab and click the classic model. Upload your skin by pressing the "BROWSE" button and click the "SAVE" button. **NOTE**: *Classic* is Steve and *Slim* is Alex.
- Minecraft Site

  Go to your [profile page](https://minecraft.net/profile) on [Minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/) and set the first dropdown box to "Classic (Steve)". You can get the default Steve skin by clicking on "Reset skin" and upload another skin if you choose too later on.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried #1, kept bringing me back to Slim Alex. But I'll try the second one, and let's hope this works...

Comment: Small problem... When it sets me back to default, it sets me back TO ALEX!! I want it to set me back to Steve as default. So that way, when I press "reset to default", it will set me to Steve, not Alex.

Comment: You said you changed something in the Minecraft folder, right? You might want to revert it, as it might confuse the game. Otherwise, try contacting Mojang.

Comment: No, I didn't change in the MC folder. When I selected 
"Browse", it asked what skin I wanted. To get it, I opened the assets folder and chose the steve skin. I didn't change anything, just selected it.